# Getting info about each redirection on the way to the final url using curl_getinfo

Tags: php, curl, redirect

is there any way to get (and, let's say display that) info about each redirection on the way to the final url using cURL (e.g. curl_getinfo function)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the header of a page using [get_meta_tags](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php). I do not know if this will get you all headers or just the last one.